# Clustering : elbow method vs silhouette score

Tags: silhouette

I tried to find optimal number of cluster using elbow method and silhouette score but the results i got are contradicting with each other. Elbow plot suggests the number of clusters to be around 7-8 but the silhouette score is maximum for 3. I don't know the actual number of clusters and I am using k means. I wanted to know if it's normal ? And how to proceed further?